# What amount of zakat we need to pay on clothes that have been gifted to us?

Tags: zakat, sadaqah

What amount of zakat we need to pay on clothes that have been gifted to us?

If someone gifts us clothes worth X, then how much zakat we need to pay on it?

Comment: and what if direct cash of X amount is given me as a money ? what amount of zakat I need to pay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing as clothes are not among the goods we need to pay Zakat for! This is as you say gifted clothes, if you were dealing with clothes than you would need to pay Zakat on your wins, but only once you reached the [nisab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisab) and a lunar year (hawl) past since that.

For details about those assets we need to pay [Zakat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakat) for just read in wikipedia and for the [calculation of the amount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculation_of_Zak%C4%81t) read also in Wikipedia.

One could say anything you use in your daily use like clothes is not among the assets for which we need to pay Zakat! Some say it is based on [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1463)

However i found [this fatwa](http://www.islamic-fatwa.com/fatwa/44688)(in Arabic) saying one can do it by estimating the value of this cloths. But I'd like to add that beside the obligatory Zakat you are free to perform sadaqah and I'd add this fatwa to that, as it seems strange.
However on the other hand I've read that is permissible to give Clothes instead of money for Zakat, which is also a statement of the given fatwa.

Also read [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/169961) on how to pay Zakat.

Comment: will you please be able to guid me on this :- http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35942/will-sadaqah-continue-to-be-considered-a-good-deed-if-its-used-to-fund-an-ongoi

Comment: Also :- http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35918/can-one-do-sadaqa-voluntary-charity-out-of-haram-income