# Can one do sadaqa (voluntary charity) out of haram income?

Tags: halal-haram, zakat, riba, sadaqah

Can one do sadaqa out of haram income?

Is it acceptable to almighty? Or almighty will punish him who will pay sadaqa out of haram income?

Comment: I've been told by some scholars that for example for riba (interest) it is acceptable to do sadaqah with this money unless it is used to feed somebody, so you could give it for example for somebody who is in need of money for let's say buy books for his kids but not for buying food (because of http://quran.com/2/275). And I'd assume that it won't be accepted for helping to build a mosque!

Answer (score 1):

No, brother. One cannot do Sadaqah out of haram income. Having a halal income source is the pre-requisite of Sadaqah. So, your Sadaqah will not be accepted, if you have done it knowingly. If you did Sadaqah unknowing that your income is truly haram, Allah might forgive you and weep to Allah for He rewards you the same as if you did Sadaqah out of your halal income source. I can't recall any direct references right now. Insha Allah, I'll put some Sahih references when Allah wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Sadaqah should be done out of halal wealth.

> #### ما تصدق أحد بصدقة من طيب، ولا يقبل الله إلا الطيب
>
> No one gives charity from a lawful source - and Allah does not accept anything except that which is lawful ...
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/24/14) and [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/12/79)</sup>

With respect to what some scholars might have said regarding riba, note that it is suggested as a way to dispose of the haram income, not to expect any reward from it.