# Will sadaqah continue to be considered a good deed if it's used to fund an ongoing project?

Tags: zakat, sadaqah

Suppose someone gives sadaqah jariya (ongoing charity) like for a free education program building.  This building is going to be built in the next 2 years.

But anyone can give sadaqah for construction of that building right away.  Is that considered as sadaqah for those 2 years?  I ask because the actual use of the building will take place after construction is completed (in 2 years).

Will that sadaqah be effective for those 2 years i.e. during the period of construction?